# Consigo conectar o birt reports a uma aplicação c#?

Tags: c#

Possuo uma aplicação c# no qual há rotinas que alimentam o banco de dados. Eu gostaria utilizar o birt reports para exibir relatórios das informações presentes no banco de dados. Há alguma maneira de na aplicação c# eu acionar o birt reports para que exiba o relatório, realizando os filtros que o usuário colocar no windows form como por exemplo, filtro de data, filtro de valor e etc ? Caso não tenha como, existe algum outro report que se adapte melhor com c#